# complex string split with multiple spaces

Tags: python, string, split

the problem I am trying to solve:

```
s = """X8 ifInDiscards=14308c X8 ifOutDiscards=133796c"""
s1 = """X3 InRXBytes=1257890123 X2 OutRXBytes=871625343 X5 OutRXBytes=71625343"""
```

Lets take the above two strings as example; I want to split each string in to separate parts:

For string s,

```
part1 = '''X8 ifInDiscards=14308c'''
part2 = '''X8 ifOutDiscards=133796c'''
```

For string s1,

```
part1 = '''X3 InRXBytes= 1257890123'''
part2 = '''X2 OutRXBytes= 871625343'''
part3 = '''X5 OutRXBytes= 71625343'''
```

So, as seen in the two string examples above, the format of string to split is:

```
'''metric1=value1 metric2=value2....metricN=valueN'''
```

The metric name can have spaces in it as seen in the above example.

So far, this is what I have tried with no luck:

```
>>> s = """X8 ifInDiscards=14308c X8 ifOutDiscards=133796c"""
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> s.split('=')
['X8 ifInDiscards', '14308c X8 ifOutDiscards', '133796c']
>>>
```

The question is how do I split the string, in the most efficient way? Here is one more approach I have tried with no luck:

```
>>> s 'X8 ifInDiscards=14308c X8 ifOutDiscards=133796c' 
>>> pattern = r'''[0-9a-zA-Z]?=[0-9a-zA-Z]? [0-9a-zA-Z]?=[0-9a-zA-Z]?''' 
>>> re.search(pattern, s)
```

The metric names can be variable length and can have multiple spaces in it....

LAST EDIT:
Here is the final approach which seems to work only for string 's' but not for string 's1', I would like to know if there is a better way to do this:

```
>>> pattern = r'''([0-9a-zA-Z ].*?=[0-9a-zA-Z ].*?) ([0-9a-zA-Z ].*?=[0-9a-zA-Z ].*)'''
>>> s
'X8 ifInDiscards=14308c X8 ifOutDiscards=133796c'
>>> re.search(pattern, s).groups()
('X8 ifInDiscards=14308c', 'X8 ifOutDiscards=133796c')
```

Comment: The question is how do I split the string, in the most efficient way?
Here is one more approach I have tried with no luck:
>>> s
'X8 ifInDiscards=14308c X8 ifOutDiscards=133796c'
>>> pattern = r'''[0-9a-zA-Z]?=[0-9a-zA-Z]? [0-9a-zA-Z]?=[0-9a-zA-Z]?'''
>>> re.search(pattern, s)

Comment: @TJonS: It could be a lot better written, but the OP has shown what he's tried. That's already a good sign.

Comment: has been edited now :)

Comment: one more last edit with a solution I came up with but is there a better way than my solution ....???

Comment: Your regexp explicitly looks for exactly two metric=value pairs, so of course it won't work for `s1`. You can either group the first half and add a `+` to it instead of copying and pasting it again, or you can just use the first half on its own and use `re.findall` instead of `re.search`.

Comment: Also, you probably want to allow anything but `'='` as part of the metric, rather than only `[0-9a-zA-Z ]`. For your two existing examples (where there are no characters outside that set) it won't make a difference, but if you have, say, a metric with a slash in it, your regexp as written will just fail to match.

Comment: Ok, I followed your suggestion but it again returns the same string:
>>> pattern = r'''([0-9a-zA-Z ].*?=[0-9a-zA-Z ].*)+'''
>>> re.search(pattern, s1).group()
'X3 InRXBytes=1257890123 X2 OutRXBytes=871625343 X5 OutRXBytes=71625343'

Comment: @ssheth: The `.*` you added to the end of the pattern causes the first group to match the first metric=value pair and all subsequent characters as one big match. This would be a lot easier if you followed by other suggestion of matching everything but `=`, and similarly matching everything but whitespace on the other side of the `=`.

Comment: @ssheth: Also, using `re.search` to find one big group—no matter how you do it—is going to just get you one big string. You need to group the parts you want as separate values by using groups. (And you probably want separate groups for the part before the `=` and the part after; otherwise, you'll just have to `.split('=')` each group after extracting it.)

Comment: Also, `[0-9a-zA-Z ].*?` means "a letter, number, or space followed by any number of other characters". If you meant "any number of letter, number, or space characters", that's `[0-9a-zA-Z ]*`. If you meant "at least one letter, number, or space", that's `[0-9a-zA-Z]+`. You may need to read through a regexp tutorial before trying to do complicated things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the result of `s.split('=')`, you should notice that each one value N-1, followed by metric N. And, since the values aren't allows to have spaces but the matrix names are, it's unambiguous how to split each element into the value and metric, right? So, then it's just a matter of shifting the list of values over by one and zipping it with the list of metrics. Just keep the edge cases in mind (the first one has no value, the last has no metric), and you should be able to write this pretty easily.

If you don't understand zipping, you can also do this explicitly:

```
d = {}
for i, part in enumerate(s1.split('=')):
    if i == 0:
        metric = part
    else:
        d[metric], _, metric = part.partition(' ')
```

But I'd strongly suggest trying to figure out the easy way, and asking for help if you get stuck.

Comment: The method using a dict and partition was the simplest and one up over the use of regular expressions. Thank you so much and I accept your answer ....

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  `re` is the right tool for the job.

Instead of trying to specify matching groups, invert your pattern and use `re.split` - think of it as a souped-up `str.split`.

I'll use a "lookaround" expression - specifically, we want to split on every whitespace character followed by a word that *doesn't* contain an `=` sign.  Otherwise known as *every space followed by a word consisting of only alphanumeric characters*.  Conveniently, we can express this very compactly: `\s(?=\w+\s)`.

```
s = """X8 ifInDiscards=14308c X8 ifOutDiscards=133796c"""
s1 = """X3 InRXBytes=1257890123 X2 OutRXBytes=871625343 X5 OutRXBytes=71625343"""

import re
pat = re.compile(r'\s(?=\w+\s)')

pat.split(s)
Out[17]: ['X8 ifInDiscards=14308c', 'X8 ifOutDiscards=133796c']

pat.split(s1)
Out[18]: 
['X3 InRXBytes=1257890123',
 'X2 OutRXBytes=871625343',
 'X5 OutRXBytes=71625343']
```

Comment: This method does not work is the metric name has no spaces in it. It works for the two examples I provided in the question - but does not work if the string is is as below: s1 = '''X3-InRXBytes=1257890123 X2_OutRXBytes=871625343'''
Thanks for providing the regex method anyways :)